# JDOM: Get all element descendants (not only direct children) with a certain name

Tags: children, jdom, descendant

EDIT: problem solved. root and descendants had different namespaces.

So, I am trying to get all descendants of the root element with a certain name, "include".

```
    Element root = doc.getRootElement();
    Namespace ns = root.getNamespace();

    ElementFilter ef = new ElementFilter("include", ns);
    Iterator<Element> childrenIter = root.getDescendants(ef);

    LinkedList<String> schemas = new LinkedList<String>();

    while (childrenIter.hasNext()) {
        Element el = childrenIter.next();
        String schemaLocation = el.getAttributeValue("schemaLocation");
        schemas.push(schemaLocation);
    }
```

Unfortunately, while loop exits immediately, hasNext() returns null, even though there is an "include" element in the tree. Is there anything I'm doing wrong? I could maybe also use getChildren() and then go deep level by level, but this is much more convenient.

```
<wsdl:definitions ...>
   <wsdl:types ...>
      <xsd:schema ...>
         <xsd:include schemaLocation="VsbKontoInfoGet_1.xsd"/>
      </xsd:schema>
   </wsdl:types>
   ...
</wsdl:definitions>
```

EDIT: problem solved. root and descendants had different namespaces.